# Bootstrap DatePicker CSS Styling not Working

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am trying to use the datepicker from the [datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/markup.html#date-range) site, but the CSS is not working as it should.

Here is my output and what I want it to look like:

[image: What I want it to look like vs What it actually looks like]

Here's a [jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/8zjh5d0u/) and the relevant code:

```html
<div class="input-daterange">
  <input type="text" class="input" value="2012-04-05" />
  <span class="add-on">to</span>
  <input type="text" class="input" value="2012-04-19" />
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id='submit'>Submit</button>
</div>
```

But I can't tell what part of the css is being overridden to change the display of the datepicker.

Comment: The datepicker in your jsfiddle isn't working for me at all...

Comment: Not hard to inspect the live html and see exactly what rules apply to any element and what the computed style is. That's all anyone here would do. Resources for demo aren't loading properly so without working demo is hard for anyone else to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classes changed from Bootstrap 2 to Bootstrap 3

The [date range markup in the docs](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/markup.html#date-range) is out of date for bootstrap 2:

```
<div class="input-daterange">
    <input type="text" class="input-small" />
    <span class="add-on">to</span>
    <input type="text" class="input-small" />
</div>
```

But if you go to the [online demo with input ranges](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=range&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox), you can see the correct markup:

```
<div class="input-daterange input-group">
    <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
    <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" />
</div>
```

#### Demo in Stack Snippets

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.1/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>


<div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
  <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="start" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
  <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="end" />
</div>
```

I'll leave adding a button as an exercise for the reader, but check out how to style [input group buttons in Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons)

Comment: Thanks - it was exactly the error going from Bootstrap 2 to 3. This fixed it.

Comment: Is it possible to label this 'joined' date picker? Would that be considered an addon, so we already used it for the middle 'to'.