# How to add separate classes to two separate dynamic datepickers?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

Essentially, it's like this:

I try to select the #fromDate and the #toDate to work on the datepicker. This does not work, despite it being the same element that the datepicker is declared in as a class.

**What I'm trying to do is:**

I want to be able to add a title to the dynamically generated datepicker class called '.datepicker-title'. However, any variation that I have done over that last four and half hours ONLY works in the console. I have tried from the original file as well, but it does not come up.

I have also tried this method as well:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    title: 'From'
})
```

But what this method does, is that it applies the title to *both* of the datepickers, and not the first input. Please don't get me wrong when I say that I have included the "#fromDate" and the "#toDate" as well within the selecter, but as I mentioned earlier, this method doesn't work.

I have two separate input fields designated below.

```
    <div class="col-sm-3 pink-inputs">
            <label>From</label>
            <input id="fromDate" class="datepicker hidden-xs" type="text" placeholder="mm/dd/yy" data-bind="value: From" />
            <span class="fa fa-angle-down icon"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 pink-inputs">
            <label>To</label>
            <input id="toDate" class="datepicker hidden-xs" type="text" placeholder="mm/dd/yy" data-bind="value: To" />
            <span class="fa fa-angle-down icon"></span>
        </div>
```

I am using bootstrap 3.0, and a [bootstrap-datepicker](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) plugin.

The class '.pink-inputs' is styling the inputs and nothing is attached to it.

Below, is my current jQuery.

```
     $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            format: "mm/dd/yy",
            maxViewMode: 2,
            todayBtn: "linked",
            orientation: "bottom left",
            autoclose: true,
            startDate: '@ViewBag.MinimumStartDate'
        });

    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        beforeShowMonth: function(){
            if($('input').attr('id') == 'fromDate'){
                title: 'From'
            }
        }
    });
```

I have checked out other similar questions such as 'How can I add class to the specific datepicker?', 'How to add specific classes to dynamic datepickers?'. Unfortunately, these solutions did not help me. I've tried several, all including variations such as:

```
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({}).addClass();
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({}).append();
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({}).addClass().append().appendTo();
```

I have also tried the beforeShowMonth, Day, Year, etc in a variety of variations.

**As a side note:**

The code that is generated by the datepicker dynamically:

```
<div style="top: 320.017px; left: 584.517px; display: block;" class="datepicker datepicker-dropdown dropdown-menu datepicker-orient-left datepicker-orient-bottom">
<table>
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th class="datepicker-title" style="display:none;" colspan="7"></th></tr>
       <tr>...</tr>
   </thead>
</table>
</div>
```

If the title is not initialized within the datepicker such as this:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
   title: 'From'
});
```

it causes (from the bootstrap-datepicker.js itself) to display: none; when the datepicker is generated in the HTML.

[image][image]

Comment: Check its helping you anyway http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037967/bootstrap-datepicker-css-styling-not-working

Comment: .datepicker-title class is used in th or tr? in screenshot th has this class and your html shows tr has this class.

Comment: The th has the class. I didn't take the time to write out the entirety of the code because I'm a work, attempting to figure this out. That was being lazy on my part; so I apologize. Also, no. I have all of the updated components (bootstrap, and the datepicker, and the classes itself).

Comment: :-(.. Still you are not clear, where actually u want to add the class. Also you said two datepicker but it has only one th

Comment: I want the class added to the .datepicker-title TH. The reason this shows only one datepicker is due to the fact that when you click on one input box, it will only show you one. It doesn't generate them both unfortunately. :/ Only one or the other. There is a lot of other code involved in the project that I'm working on such as a CMS & Knockout.JS. Another thing it mention is that I'm not using a daterange. Just two separate datepickers

Answer (score 0):

This is not working for you?

```
 $(".datepicker-title").each(function(i){
        $(this).addClass("style" + i);
    });

<div style="top: 320.017px; left: 584.517px; display: block;" class="datepicker datepicker-dropdown dropdown-menu datepicker-orient-left datepicker-orient-bottom">
<table>
   <thead>
       <tr class="datepicker-title" style="display:none;" colspan="7"></tr>
       <tr class="datepicker-title" style="display:none;" colspan="7"></tr>
   </thead>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, share the html generated.

Comment: The classes are added to the input itself, not to the HTML that is generated dynamically by the datepicker. Maybe I did not convey that clearly enough?

Comment: ".datepicker" is input element rite? thats where the class will be added. Where else do you want to add it?

Comment: Sorry! Ohkai, the generated code is placed at the bottom of the post. I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: <tr class="datepicker-title" style="display:none;" colspan="7"></tr> . do you want to add the class to this element?

Comment: Yes, that's the element that I would prefer to have the classes added too. However, I have changed the selector to that and it remains the same. I also apologize for mistyping the ('.datepicker') class.

Comment: Updated the answer, check its working for u? if not try to give some delay and apply the style.

Comment: I have images of what the actual generated code looks like, plus the code that I have added within the jQuery. I will add them to the above post.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('#toDate').datepicker({
        format: "mm/dd/yy",
        maxViewMode: 2,
        todayBtn: "linked",
        orientation: "bottom left",
        autoclose: true,
        startDate: '@ViewBag.MinimumStartDate',
        title: 'To'
    });

    $('#fromDate')
        .datepicker({
            format: "mm/dd/yy",
            maxViewMode: 2,
            todayBtn: "linked",
            orientation: "bottom left",
            autoclose: true,
            startDate: '@ViewBag.MinimumStartDate',
            title: 'From'
        });
```

I was over complicating the matter.